# Ошибка в python venv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Такая вот ошибка:

```
$ python -m venv higl

Error: Command '['/home/runesmaker/pyCode/higl/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Что не так? Что делать?

Только установил 3.7 и вот так работает venv. Система: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

Comment: Попробуйте `python3.7 -m venv higl`

Comment: То же самое. Самое обидное, что нет репорта.

Comment: В общем смирился! И использую virtualenv. Но спасибо за помощь.